# How to implement deleteValues (int values) method for a custom ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am implementing my custom ArrayList class for integers with the help of an array, and I would like to be able to delete a certain value from my array. My problem is when there are many same delete-able value next to each other, I am getting two 0s next to each other which leads to a bug. i tried to solve it for a couple of hours without luck. Here is my code:

```
    int max=10;
    public int[] a = new int[max];

    @Override
    public void deleteValues(int value) {
    int tempIndex=0;

    for (int i = 0; i <50 ; i++) {
        if (a[tempIndex] == value) {
            a[tempIndex] = a[tempIndex + 1];
            a[tempIndex + 1] = 0;
        } else if (a[tempIndex] == 0) {
            a[tempIndex] = a[tempIndex + 1];
            a[tempIndex + 1] = 0;

        } else {
            tempIndex++;

        }

    }


}
```

My array looks like that before deleting the value (4):

```
[4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3]
```

This is the wrong result after running the code:

```
[2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3]
```

What I would like to achieve:`[2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

My question is: What would be the best approach to make the code work, using as few loop as possible?

Comment: Where's the `ArrayList`? What's `a`?

Comment: sorry, a is an array, and  I try to implement my own Arraylist class.

Comment: Do you want to delete element from array or set it to 0?

Comment: Is it obligatory to make a solution without regular ArrayList?

Comment: Yes. It should be without regular ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems in your code is that you're always copying the element at index `tempIndex+1` into `tempIndex`: it's always the next element.
In fact, after deleting let's say `5` elements from the array, you'll have to copy `tempIndex+5` into `tempIndex`.

I think this is a good way of doing it:

```
public void deleteValues(int[] a, int value) {
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i]!=value) {
            a[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }   
    }
    // fill the rest of the array with zeros
    while(j<a.length) {
        a[j] = 0;
        j++;
    }   
}
```

Basically, you keep two indices: `i` and `j`.
The index `i` follows the "original" array, while index `j` follows the "new" array (after deletion).
Index `i` loops over all the elements: if `a[i]` **is not** equal to `value`, copy it into its new position `j` and increment both `j` and `i`. If `a[i]` **is** equal to `value`, skip it and increment `i` without incrementing `j`.
After all the elements have been copied or skipped, fill the end of the array with zeros.

Sample input:

```
a     = {4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3}
value = 4
```

Output:

```
a     = {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void deleteValues(int[] a, int value) {
    int newSize = a.length;
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != value) {
            if (i != current) {
                a[current] = a[i];
                newSize--;
            }
            current++;
        }
    }
    //use first newSize values, for example you can copy to new array
    System.out.println("New size = " + newSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use iterator:

```
List<Integer> numbers = ....
Iterator<Integer> i = numbers.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   Integer num = i.next(); 
   // add here your custom code
   i.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            int tempIndex,index;
            for (index = 0, tempIndex = 0; index < valuesArray.length; index++) {
                if (valuesArray[index] != valToDelete) {
                    valuesArray[tempIndex++]=valuesArray[index];
                }
            }
            while(tempIndex<valuesArray.length){
                valuesArray[tempIndex++]=0;
            }
```